# UISearchBar showsCancelButton animation complete

Tags: swift, animation, uisearchbar

I need to know when the cancel button of the UISearchBar has finished his animation after calling

```
searchBar.setShowsCancelButton(false, animated: true)
```

I've tried this

```
UIView.animateWithDuration(3, animations: {
    self.searchBarView.searchBar.showsCancelButton = false
         }, completion: {finished in
         print(finished)
})
```

but the completion block gets triggered immediatly, any solution would be appreciated

Comment: Use the closure expression for more than `print(finished)`. You could add a member, 'cancelDoneAnimating' and set it to true in your closure. Maybe not the most efficient, but another function could access that member to check the status

Comment: If i add a member in the closure and i set it to true and i write a function that gets triggered when the member value become true why this function will be called at the end of the animation? (considering the completion block is triggered immediatly)

Comment: I see your point. I suppose the ugly solution would be to add a delay to the closure that is the same length of time as the animation, then set the member to true.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use layoutIfNeeded() to update view in UIView.animateWithDuration(...)

try this code:

```
import UIKit

class ViewController: UIViewController {

@IBOutlet var searchBar: UISearchBar!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

@IBAction func touchUpInside(sender: UIButton) {
    searchBar.showsCancelButton = !searchBar.showsCancelButton
    UIView.animateWithDuration(3, animations: {
        self.searchBar.layoutIfNeeded()
        }, completion: {finished in
            print("Animation finished")
    })
}
}
```

and storyboard: 
[image]